# How to include bluemix text to speech services using Node

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have a bluemix app using dialog service and I am trying to include the text to speech service using:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
```

in my index.js.

I get an undefined error.

I already tried adding npm install watson-developer-cloud on the build pipeline but it does not work. I also tried browserify.

Comment: There is a good example in their doc, do you have any other errors that could help us help you besides just "undefined"? First off, you should be using `var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');`
` https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud#text-to-speech

Comment: it says require is not defined and i read that i cannot use require in jquery or on the client side. I looked into browserify too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.js declare

> `var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
>   app.get('/test', function(req, res) { //call all req function here  });`

In your Index.js Add

```
$('#text_to speech').click(function(e){

$.ajax({ type: 'GET', data: { text: "text to speech" }, url: '/test' , success: function(response) { console.log('success');  } });
}
```

Comment: thanks - turns out i was trying to do a require(watson) inside of my client side code

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at more of your build pipeline, it's difficult to see if your npm install command is running correctly. I suggest you add watson-developer-cloud to the dependencies list in your package.json

Comment: yes i added npm watson-developer-cloud to my pipeline but it does not seem to do anything to fix the issue